# Eloquent query not working in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have an Eloquent query as given below

```
         $mandate_list = Mandate::where('mandate_status','Pending')
                        ->orWhere('mandate_status','Awaiting approval')
                        ->whereNotIn('user_id',Sentry::getUser()->id)
                        ->get();
```

Where am I wrong?
This is not working.
But when I give this

```
   $mandate_list = Mandate::where('mandate_status','Pending')
                        ->orWhere('mandate_status','Awaiting approval')->get();
```

It is working fine. I need to display mandates that does not belongs to the current user.
Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: Please provide a more details.

Comment: @HasibMahmud I want to retrieve data from 'mandates' table where mandate_status = 'Pending' or mandate_status= 'Awaiting approval' and the mandate user_id != current user id ie.Sentry::getUser()->id.

Comment: can you share error details please. and also try echo Sentry::getUser()->id

Comment: What error do u get??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you got an error at this line.

```
->whereNotIn('user_id',Sentry::getUser()->id)
```

The second parameter of function `whereNotIn` need to be an array

you can replace it with

```
->where('user_id', '<>' ,Sentry::getUser()->id)
```

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects

Is this what you are looking for?